# I want to add Facebook Conversion Measurement pixel in my React Click Event, but it didn't work?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, reactjs

I use react to build our e-commerce website. And we try to add Facebook pixel to track our 'AddtoBag' event. According Facebook developer(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ads-for-websites/tag-api/#dynamicevents), I put my code

```
fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
  content_ids: [this.props.data.id],
  value: this.props.data.price, 
  currency: 'TWD'
});
```

in my click event. Following is my full code.

```
confirm() {
    this.setState({ showModal: false });

    var data = {
      id: this.props.data.id,
      number: this.refs.inputNumber.value
    }

    // Facebook tracking
    fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
      content_ids: [this.props.data.id],
      value: this.props.data.price, 
      currency: 'TWD'
    });

    // Submit form via jQuery/AJAX
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/main/main/modifybagquantity',
      data: data
    })
},
```

My question is that After I clicked button, I still cannot receive any 'AddToCart ' event. How do I add Facebook Conversion Measurement pixel in my React Click Event and I can get event from my website?

Comment: Do you get any errors in the console? Is the click event attached to an `href` that's getting in the way? Can you see the network dispatch? Can you confirm that the `confirm` method is for sure being called?

Comment: I don't get any errors. The href and confirm method are also perfect. The only problem is I cannot  track my 'AddtoBag' event.

Comment: What I meant about the `href` is that, if you have one, you may need to prevent the default action to give the event time to process. If that method is indeed running, but the event is not triggering (e.g. a log before and after it both print out) and you're not following a url, then the problem has nothing to do with React.

Comment: Sorry, please forgive my poor English. Did you mean if my AJAX code work correctly, I might not get or trigger my fbq event? And I think my click event is not attatched to an href. This is how I use  `<Button onClick={this.confirm}>確定</Button>`. The button is a ReactBootstrap var.